# Capture windows 10 restart/shutdown events using C# winforms

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, system-shutdown, windows-10-desktop

I am trying to capture windows 10 restart/shutdown events using C# winforms. I am writing an application that requires the complete log of idle time, lock/unlock and windows restart/shutdown/logoff timestamps.

Can you help me in guiding with related links or posts, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event handler method to the [SystemEvents.SessionEnding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) event, and your handler method will be called each time the event is raised. Handling this event will allow you to cancel the pending log off or shut down.